# How to reload a select box of posts dynamically?

Tags: jquery, metabox, get-posts

I'm using custom meta boxes for a project. I have created a custom taxonomy (select box) and I have another select box populated with Posts. I need to only load the posts based on the selection of the first select box (taxonomy). How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What you're searching for is "chained selection" - this is something that you've to build yourself. Not going to answer as it's tons of work. But +1 for the question - maybe search will bring something up, as this isn't asked the first time.

Comment: Could be an Answer, but it's just a hint: the only instance of [`+chained +selection`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bchained+%2Bselection) in this Stack is [this Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/20753/12615) which has a link to a tutorial, ***but*** the server side PHP script of that tutorial must be adapted to WordPress to answer this Question here...