# dropdowboxes with pre-selected custom fields optios that filters the results according seach needs

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search, dropdown

In my site I have one custom post types with custom taxonomies:

custom post_type=listings --> Category --> Tags

Along with it, I have some custom fields to separate them by country, state, region.

The problem is that I need too supply an efficient form for users to perform a search and I would like to create several dropdowboxes with pre-selected custom fields optios that filters the results according their needs...

eg. A user selects country-a and a second dropdowbox becomes active with states from that country and after that another one becomes active with regions from country a. Then, the user inserts the search term and gets their results filtered

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic User State & City selection](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20744/dynamic-user-state-city-selection)

Comment: @brasofilo The answer to the question you linked to contains just a dead link!?

Comment: @toscho I'm being able to see it right now... (?) . . . . Shall I copy the tutorial inside the Answer?

Comment: @brasofilo I get _Forbidden_ with some browsers, real content with others. You cannot copy other peoples article to our site.